# Visual C++: Invalid allocation size. Why is this happening?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

Im the process of learning C++. I got stuck debugging some of my code on VC++, with the following error-

```
Debug Error
*path to filename.exe*
Invalid allocation size:429496723 bytes.
```

The error precisely occurs when the debugger reaches the following block: **EDIT**: Ive added the entire main function to help check if *maxlen* is taking on any unexpected values(none that I notice though)

```
int main(){

    vector <Student_info> students;

    Student_info record;

    string::size_type maxlen=0;// length of the longest name

    //read and store all the students data.

    //maxlen contains the length of the name of the longest student.

    while (read(cin,record)){
    // find the length of the longest name
        max(maxlen,record.name.size());
        //add the student record to the vector.

        students.push_back(record);
    }
    //arrange the records alphabetically.
    sort(students.begin(),students.end(),compare);// this may look weird but the fact that the names have to be compared is checked using the predicate.

        //write out the names and grades.


        for(vector<Student_info>::size_type i =0;i!=students.size();i++){

            //padding to ensure that there is vertical alignment.
            cout<<students[i].name<<string(maxlen+1-students[i].name.size(),' ');// debugger stops here!
            //compute grade.
            try{
                double final_grade=grade(students[i]);
                streamsize prec=cout.precision();
                cout<<setprecision(3)<<final_grade<<setprecision(prec);
            }
            catch(domain_error e){
            //catch error if hw vector is empty!

                e.what();

            }
            cout<<endl;

            }
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with whatever `maxlen` is...?

Comment: One of the names is longer that `maxlen`.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Ive added the entire code associated with main.

Comment: @molbdnilo: i was using strings of length 15 characters so I dont think thats  a possibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might look at the line:

```
max(maxlen,record.name.size());
```

Is it possible that you meant:

```
maxlen = max(maxlen,record.name.size());
```

Comment: *maxlen* is defined as `size_type`. Ive added more relevant code, do take a look.

Comment: From the new code I can see that maxlen=0, confirming that you are trying to allocate a negative length string.

Comment: er how does that help infer; that Im trying to allocate a negative length string, and what exactly do I correct?

Comment: What Im trying to do is to simply pad all the listed students names by names with an calculated amount of spaces so that they align vertically.The spaces are calculated by first finding out the length of the longest name in the list, this is stored in `maxlen`. Then for the name of each student, there is `maxlen+1-students.name.size()` spaces , and in the case of the student with the longest name, there will be just one space after the name(maxlen+1-maxlen).

Comment: Did you try the maxlen=(maxlen,x) fix?

Answer (score 3):

You're never assigning a value to maxlen after initliazing it to 0.  Then later you're subtracting 1 from that giving a negative offset.

Inside your first while loop you probably want...

```
   maxlen = max( maxlen, record.name.size() );
```